# Android WebView Hardware Accelerated Keyboard Glitch

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, hardware-acceleration, duplication

When WebView is hardware accelerated, clicking on input field causes keyboard to appear and html is redrawed shifted and duplicated for a moment:

1) When soft keyboard is appearing WebView pans its content to bottom-left, then againt to normal position. Causes short view-able duplication.

2) When changing keyboards (ex. abc->numbers) contents are panned down by keyboard height and then back to normal position. Causes short view-able duplication.

Tested on two Android 4.0 tablets, if hardware accelerations is turned off no such glitches appear.

I failed to found *any* information on this, has anyone experienced same problem?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally found some solutions:

1. The entire WebView content moves by layout margin width, so setting it to `0px` fixes this problem.
2. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for WebView activity.

Comment: I think I'm experiencing similar problem, where everything in webview seems to shift a few pixels to the right (and stays there) when I go to input field. when you say layout margin - do you mean the outer parent (html/body/#wrapper)?