# WebView flickering when keyboard show up in PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am developing a web app on PhoneGap framework.

I found a weird situation which only happend on Android 4.0 ICS device.

when I tap on an input, the whole view will shrink to fit the new height, it happend again after I push the back button to dismiss the keyboard, flickering again.

the problem only happend when I wrap the code inside native container(PhoneGap), it won't flickering in stock browser.

any ideas?

PhoneGap 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer on SO.

[Android WebView Hardware Accelerated Keyboard Glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946086/android-webview-hardware-accelerated-keyboard-glitch)

set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity manifest file,

it solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem seting:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

in your activity manifest file (my_app/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml).

Answer (score -1):

i have tried this, and it worked form me :)

set this line in activity tag of android manifest file
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"